# Why isn't the socket binding correctly in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, binding

I have written some Python bindings for a third party library written in C++. When I use the library in Python it sends data over the network but it does not receive anything (it does both in C++). If I run the same test program in two different C++ processes it crashes because they are both trying to bind a socket to the same port.

But when I run the python version together with the C++ version this does not happen, leading me to believe that the Python version is not binding the socket correctly. All the same C++ functions are being called by the Python code.

However, the Python code does get a socket binding error when run twice at the same time. I have checked that the port and address variables are the same in Python and C++ so they shouldn't be binding to different addresses. Can anyone give me an idea of what might be happening here?

Comment: show us the code.

Comment: You can check whether it binds to a port and which one it uses by `netstat -n -l -p` (or window's `netstat`, if not *nix system). Its hard to guess whats wrong without either sources or some kind of debug info.

Comment: Are you binding through the C++ library?  Or using sockets in Python?

Comment: I was binding through the C++ library. I used netstat and found that it was binding the default port instead of the one that I was explicitly setting, this lead me to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You should answer question yourself now, in case someone faces similar problem.